# how to get this react ajax response and set state

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

```
class Videos extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        videoslist:[];
    }


    _getVideo(skip,limit){

        var self= this;    
        var sess=localStorage.getItem("sessionId");

        $.ajax({
            method:'GET',
            url:'videos',
            data:{'sessionId':sess,
                 'skip':skip,
                 'limit':limit},
            success:function(res){
               this.setState({videoslist:res.data})
            }.bind(this)
        });       
   }
 componentWillMount(){
       this._getVideo(0,10);
   }
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'videoslist' of null  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null**

Answer (score 1):

you have wrong state initializing

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        videoslist: []
    }
}
```

Comment: then what's the problem to make this as accepted answer?

Comment: Click the check mark on the left to set it as the correct answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work